# how to use the session to save data in angular,nodejs,socket.io

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets

> I need to use the session to save data in angularjs,nodejs and socket.io. When I close the page of my siteweb, I want the session is cleared also.
>   for example:

I have a value usename in the function express

```
app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
    var username=req.session.username;
});
```

and now I need to use this value in the function socket

```
socket.on("message",function(){
   var usernameSocket= username;           
})
```

but the value of usernameSocket is not good

and when I am in angularjs,how can I get the value of req.session.username, and save it in my sessionStorage of angular?

thanks

Comment: are you using express for your nodejs server?

Comment: yes I use express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using express try using [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session)

Essentially you alias express session like so:
`sess=req.session;`

Then you reference this and use it like any other session management (in PHP or whatnot):

get - `console.log(sess.email)`

set - `sess.email=req.body.email`

**[Here's a great rundown on how it works](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/)**